# Is Tor Browser vulnerable to tracking via HSTS Super Cookies?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, https

Is Tor Browser vulnerable to the HSTS Super Cookies tracking technique described [here](http://www.radicalresearch.co.uk/lab/hstssupercookies)?

(Initial experimentation with Tor Browser 4.0.3 suggests it's not: I get a different tracking id after selecting "New identity" and revisiting the page)

Answer (score 3):

"Implementation Status: Currently, HSTS state is cleared by New Identity, but we don't defend against the creation of these cookies between New Identity invocations" https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/